# Rails rake task for loading live (MySQL) database to local development database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

For years I've used a ssh pipe from `mysqldump` on the live server to `mysql` on my development machine for getting a copy of the current data.

```
ssh -C <server> mysqldump --opt <live_database_name> |mysql <local_dev_database_name>
```

Where `-C` enables ssh compression and `--opt` enables quickness and completeness.

Does anyone have a rails-ish equivalent rake task for this? Ideally it'd take the database names from config/database.yml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/750129

This is not an elegant solution. It's basically a wrapper for your old method, so it's not even compatible with other database drivers.

But it is something you can put in your SCM under lib/tasks to share it with other developers on your team. It also uses config data from your existing config/database.yml file. You define the live db by simply adding another branch to that file and it uses the same key names that Rails do.

Maybe it would even make sense to reuse the production database configuration.

Comment: This looks like just the ticket. Thank you!

Comment: And well done in earning a bounty as your *first points* on SO. Good going kid, you're gonna be a star ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one I use for a Postgres database: https://gist.github.com/748222.

There are three tasks: `db:download`, `db:replace` and `db:restore`. `db:restore` is just a wrapper around the other two.

I'd say you could do something similar for Mysql pretty quickly as well. I just use the latest backup in this case instead of creating it at runtime.

Comment: This looks like just the ticket apart from the file copying rather than pipe-over-ssh part. I'll see about hacking it up for my needs tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with coding in Ruby you might want to look into [seed-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) and [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).

Oh, I forgot to mention [standalone-migrations](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations). It comes with a Rake task for schema migrations.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really looking for a faked/seed data solution, rather, a generic rake task for loading the live database to the local development one. It's hard to diagnose issues with the live data without the live data :-)

Comment: Ok noodl. Hope you find what you're looking for!

Comment: It would be pretty easy to get rake to run the above command template substituting values from config/database.yml but there's no place in most apps where the live server's hostname is stored (for obvious reasons). Perhaps this would be better tackled by capistrano/thor, if I were to use one of those. Like the above command though, I find deployment can be taken care of (assuming git) with a single command 'line'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using rake to do this, I'd use a capistrano task, as your capistrano tasks would already have knowledge of where the production server is, etc...

Comment: You're quite right that capistrano would be a great choice for implementing this but I typically don't use it and would rather have a solution that relied only on rails/rake.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to create another "instance" in database.yml (for your live server) and put the correct host there (and leave the rest username/passwords etc). In your rake task you would load the database yaml file, read the host and go on with your command line slurpiness. It could easily be wrapped up in a rake task.